# Ошибка в Python связанная с импортированием random в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Я совсем недавно изучаю питон, начал писать простенькую игрушку 21 и возникло это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите [mre] и ошибку в текстовом виде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно дело в том, что в проекте уже есть файл с названием random.py. Вам нужно удалить его или переименовать. Программа импортирует не системный модуль, а то что вы написали в этом файле, поэтому не находится аттрибут randint.